# How to remove special characters while saving xml string using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-cmdlet

Following is the powershell code which I am using to remove parent node from the web.config file:

```
 $c = "C:\test\web.config"
     $xml = ( Get-Content $c)
     $ConnectionString = $xml.configuration.appSettings.add | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'ConnectionString'}
     $xml.configuration.RemoveChild($ConnectionString.ParentNode)
     $xml.save($c)

After removing <appSettings> tag from web.config file. Some special Characters like &#xA; are adding to web.config file as below:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, &#xA;        System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, &#xA;        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
   </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Please let me know how to save xml file without special characters like `&#xA;` and new line

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue, I filtered all non ascii-256 chars with this regex

```
$myText = # your text here
$cleanText = ($myText -replace"[^\x00-\xFF]","");
```

Are you sure this chars should be removed? You can also try to change encoding with something like this

```
$myText | Out-File -FilePath "yourPath" -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: I have used both [^\x00-\xFF] and utf8 encoding for xml file still same special characters i.e, &#xD;&#xA; and &#xA; are coming instead of white spaces